# Default value in input octave

Tags: validation, default-value, octave

Is there a method to add a default value for input? (in Octave )
Sounds so simple but I can't find it. 
I just want to give the user a possibility to pres ENTER if the default value is ok, or to change it and then ENTER.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
function val = get_response(default="Y")
  val = input("Your choice? [Y]/N ", "s");
  if isempty(val)
    val = default;
  endif
endfunction
```

I wrapped this into a function but you can use the enclosed code directly, of course.